# Two devices calling the same servlet, one receives the intended response, the other receives null, but call is definetly made with valid parameters

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a multiplayer card game (this context only involves 2 players). One player invites other players. Once the game initiator sends all the invites, he goes to a "WaitingRoom" activity, whereby every 5 seconds he makes a call to the server to see if all the other players have have accepted the Invite, at which point he will proceed to the gameplay activity.

When the invitee receives and accepts the invite, he also goes to the waiting room activity and follows the same procedure(check until ready).

Problem: When the invitee accepts the invite, the initiator's next call to the server returns a positive response, and he proceeds to the game activity. However, when the invitee makes the same call to check on the room status, The POST request keeps returning null, yet the HTTP Monitor (netbeans) shows that the call was made and the parameters were valid. I added `println()` commands and also noticed that the servlet is only being executed partially. I have been stuck on this for days and cannot figure out where the issue is.

Server Code:

```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

System.out.println("Check Room doPost");
String sessionID = request.getParameter("SessionID");
String room = "ROOM_"+sessionID;

System.out.println("Room: "+room);
int totalPlayers = 0;
int totalActive = 0;
ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();

try(PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()){

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp:localhost/~/j2324", "vernon", "");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    System.out.println("Connected to database");
    //invitees call ends here and returns null
    ResultSet rSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from "+room+";");

    while(rSet.next()){
        totalPlayers++;
        usernames.add(rSet.getString("username"));
    }

    System.out.println("Got usernames. Total = " + totalPlayers);

    for(int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++){
        ResultSet temp = statement.executeQuery("select * from USERS where username = '"+usernames.get(i)+"';");
        temp.next();
        if(temp.getString("status").equals("playing")){
            totalActive ++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total active players = " + totalActive);

    if(totalPlayers == totalActive){

        out.println("ready");
       System.out.println("Ready sent");

    }else{
        out.println("not ready");
        System.out.println("Not ready sent");
    }

}catch(SQLException| ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Client Code:

```
public class WaitingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String sessionID;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_waiting);
Intent intent = getIntent();
sessionID = intent.getStringExtra("SessionID");

checkRoomReady();

}

public void checkRoomReady(){

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(WaitingActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Waiting for players to accept     invite");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        String url = "http://192.168.1.72:8084/Jersey2324/CheckRoom";

        try{

            OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
            RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("SessionID", sessionID)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(response.body().charStream());

            String serverResponse = in.readLine();


            //this is what the invitee gets
            if(serverResponse == null || !response.isSuccessful()){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                checkRoomReady();
                            }
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                });

            }else if(serverResponse.equals("not ready")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                checkRoomReady();
                            }
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                });
            }

            //as opposed to this
            else{

                Intent intent = new Intent(WaitingActivity.this, MultiPlayerBoard.class);
                intent.putExtra("SessionID", sessionID);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }catch(IOException e){

        }

    }
});
thread.start();
```

}